# MySQLi Update Query works manually but no in script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making an script that pings to IP and X value is saved in a MySQL db for statistic purposes.

If I take the echo (of the update data, in the mid of function) and execute directly in PHPMyAdmin works perfectly, but no the same query in the PHP code, I've checked all and I dont see the error, lol.

This is the code:

```
    /*
    ID  Primary int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT   Change Change   Drop Drop  
More
    2   ip  text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None             Change Change   Drop Drop  
More
    3   timeping    text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None             Change Change   Drop Drop  
More
    4   jsondata    text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None             Change Change   Drop Drop  
More
    5   timeop  text    latin1_swedish_ci   
    */

$db = new mysqli ("127.0.0.1", "R_status", "PASSHIDDEN", "R_status");
//$totalIP = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data");
//$resultado = $totalIP->fetch_array();
//print($resultado[0]);
$prepare = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE timeping='0' LIMIT 1");
$ars = $prepare->fetch_array();
//echo($prepare-num_rows);
function pingAddress($ip) {
    $pingresult = exec("/bin/ping -c 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);
    $status++;
    global $ars;
    // 0 = NO COMPROBADO
    // 1 = EN LINEA
    // 2 = CAIDO
    echo("UPDATE data SET `timeping`='$status' WHERE ID=".$ars[0]."");
    $db->query("UPDATE data SET `timeping`='$status' WHERE ID=".$ars[0]."");
    die();
}
print_r($ars);
pingAddress($ars[1]);

?>
```

Here's one output of this code:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [ID] => 2 [1] => 77.26.0.2 [ip] => 77.26.0.2 [2] => 0 [timeping] => 0 [3] => 0 [jsondata] => 0 [4] => 0 [timeop] => 0 ) 

UPDATE data SET `timeping`='1' WHERE ID=2
```

That update string works in PhpMyAdmin but no directly in the PHP script, stranger for me, because I didn't found a solution in google.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Scope issue, variables are not available in the scope of your `pingAddress()` function. Either use `global` or explicitly pass the variables to the function.

Comment: That's and internal script, not need to filter any data from user @tadman anyway i'll see  `bind_param` for info, solution aported by @rajdeep-paul was my solution

Comment: It's an internal script today. It's dangerous to have ticking time-bomb code like this which could be deployed somewhere else without you knowing. Do it right the first time and you won't have problems. It's the safe thing to do and it takes only a few more lines of code to avoid what could be a very expensive blunder.

Comment: applied recommendations and code from the answer and comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, your current way of doing the query.. even with the added `global $db;` is highly insecure and is sensible to SQL-Injection attacks.

I suggest you do your update query as follows, to avoid the risk of SQL-Injections happening. However private you intend this to be or not, ignorance is no excuse in safety!

```
// $db is your database connection
$query = "UPDATE `data` SET `timeping`=? WHERE `ID`=?"; // the query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query); // prepares the query for params
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $status, $ars[0]); // bind two ints -> 'ii' -> passing the args behind it
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // run the stmt
// use following to check the number of affected rows:
// mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) // highly recommended to check for any malicious activity!
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); // close it -> just to do it neatly
```

An additional check through `preg_match` is advised to prevent any malicious code from beeing inserted when this does accidentaly get into the wrong hands. Doing `mysqli_real_escape_string`, stripping the tags and trimming might be good ideas aswell.

Comment: Updated code like youre telling, i'll convert to object oriented and apply this to all codes, thank you

Comment: Have a read into [here](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) if you want to use that feature for other queries aswell. (and use output binding and `fetch_assoc`)